# Importing class modules into another class

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I'm attempting to import some classes into my main class, but get an error; Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import on the line import ApiDto = Model.DtoModel.ApiDto;

[image]

There's two DTO models sharing the same module name across two files;

```
export module DtoModel { 
    export class ApiDto {
    }
    export class ApiDtoItem { 
        public method: string;
        public object: any;
    }
}

export module DtoModel { 
    export class User { 
        public userNo: number;
    }
}
```

This is the project structure;

[image]

Main.ts

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />

import * as Model from "../DtoModels/./ApiDto";

// breaks on next line!
import ApiDto = Model.DtoModel.ApiDto;

export class Main {
    private Url: string;

    constructor() {
        var apidto = new ApiDto();
        this.Url = "http://localhost:80/api/main";

        var response = jQuery.post(this.Url, (data: ApiDto, textStatus: string, jqXHR: JQueryXHR) => {
           apidto = data;
        });

        console.log(response);
    }
}

var main: Main = new Main();
```

Here are my compile options:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are compiling your typescript to ES6 (`"target": "es6"` in tsconfig.json). But the browser doesn't natively support ES6 imports/exports - thus the error.

Comment: Strange I thought Chome 54 or Firefox 49 supported ES6

Comment: right - most of ES6 features are supported. But browsers can't load modules - that's why import/export is not implemented in any browsers natively at this time. You have to use bundlers - Webpack, Browserify, Rollup - or try module loaders like SystemJS

Comment: ES6 Module loader standard is being developed, please see https://whatwg.github.io/loader/

Comment: Thanks, I realised WebStorm ran TypeScript 1.8 internally and played around with including Webpack.

Comment: WebStorm indeed bundles TypeScript 1.8, but it's not used internally - types resolving, completion, etc. are based on proprietary typescript parser. The bundled compiler is only used for compiling Typescript. Note also that you can choose a different compiler version, you shouldn't necessary use the built-in compiler